# What's the relationship between the sift features and the minutiae features?

Tags: computer-vision

As we know, in the field of fingerprint or palmprint recognition, both the [sift features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) and the [minutiae features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minutiae) can be used to construct the descriptor. However, what's the relationship  between them?